# Can you POST in a GET Method in Rest services?

Tags: rest, soapui

I am working on a SoapUI automation project for Restful service.I'm new to SoapUi and Restful services itself.
I have the Rest API generated in SoapUI. I don't have any sample requests given by the developer so I am working on creating the requests myself. I only have a JSON contract document to refer to which was created for the UI developers. Now according to the specification documents, some get methods in the API's are supposed to have two parameters "token" and "ContextName". However, when I imported the WADL file in SoapUI, the request body only has the "token" parameter. So am I manually supposed to add the other missing parameter in my requests? and is it possible to create a POST(rest test request) in a GET resource?

Comment: Without seeing the spec you were given by your development team, it would be extremely difficult to give you a clear answer. Have a read through this: http://www.soapui.org/Best-Practices/understanding-rest-headers-and-parameters.html and http://www.soapui.org/Best-Practices/testing-the-other-verbs.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can have multiple body parameters (or if you can, it's certainly not a good practice!). Check to see if the ContextName parameter is a different type of parameter such as a query or path parameter (called template parameter in SoapUI). Here is some info about different types of REST parameters in SoapUI: http://www.soapui.org/rest-testing/understanding-rest-parameters.html

I'm not sure what you mean in your second question. Perhaps you want to write a Test Case with multiple Test Steps (a GET and a POST)? Check out this link: http://www.soapui.org/functional-testing/structuring-and-running-tests.html Also look at the other sections under Functional Testing to learn how to control the flow of test steps.